# What is the correct syntax for declaring a function pointer with generic class pointer as an argument?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, types

Using C++11 switch with MinGW tool chain:

I want to set up a generic event handler that will take a pointer argument (reference is also fine) to any type of class I might want.

What is the correct syntax for declaring a function pointer with generic class pointer as an argument?

I tried:

```
typedef void ( *OnChange ) ( class* );
```

*Compiler error:*

> **typedef ‘OnChange’ is initialized (use decltype instead)**

I am not familiar with decltype(), and from what I read about it, it isn't what I need.

I also tried:

```
typedef void ( *OnChange ) ( auto* );
```

*Compiler error:*

> **parameter declared ‘auto’**

I assume this means that auto cannot be used for parameter declarations.

How should I declare the typedef? (Or maybe I need to do something different?)

Comment: And what is a generic class here? If it is templatized then you can use the type of the template

Comment: How would you use this function pointer?

Comment: Such typedef should go inside a template `struct` or `class`, then you can easily refer to the template parameter(s).

Comment: You might be looking for _type erasure_. We can't be sure unless you clarify some of the questions asked by other commenters.

Answer (score 3):

C++ is a statically typed language. As much as features like `auto` and templates may make you think otherwise, the C++ compiler *must* know at compile-time the type of everything in the system. `auto` and templates are allowed it to deduce types in certain circumstances, but that's only when the compiler certainly knows what that type is.

There is no such thing in C++ as a "generic class pointer". Every pointer *must* be a pointer to an explicit type. Every pointer to one type is a fundamentally different type from a pointer to some other type. C++ does not consider pointers to different types to be interchangeable (though it does allow a few implicit casts, such as a conversion from pointers to a `void*`).

What you need is not a function pointer; pointers must have explicit types and you need to hold something that *isn't* an explicit type. What you need is a *functor*; that works because the `operator()` method can be a *template*. However, this will require you to either make the class holding this functor a template (the functor's type is passed in by the user as the template parameter), or you will need to make your class use type erasure techniques, so that it can call any functor value the user passes in and registers.

The latter would require something like `std::function`, only with an arbitrary, templated `operator()` function call, rather than for a concrete, typed function.

Comment: "There is no such thing in C++ as a "generic class pointer" Understood. I am not that experienced in C++. I am accustomed to languages like Object Pascal, C# (they are also statically typed) and Python, which have a base **Object Type** that all other objects inherit from, so you can declare a function that takes "Object*" as an argument and will accept any Object type as a parameter. This is not like **class** in C++ which is not a base type for other classes but a keyword for declaring types. As I thought about it some more, I realized I would have to use templates to get what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use something like this :

```
template<typename T>
struct X{
 typedef void  (*OnChange)  ( T* );
};

void foo(int* ptr){
}

class Test;

int main(){
    int a=12;
    X<int>::OnChange ptr= foo;
    ptr(&a);

    X<Test>::OnChange o;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

template typedef are possible with C++11 compilers with using syntax :

```
template < typename T >
using OnChange = void (*)( T * );
```

Comment: You cannot declare any pointer of type `OnChange`, since it isn't a *type* at all; it's a *template*. Technically a template alias, but same thing.